# Cannot ping Server 2008 over VPN

Tags: vpn, rdp

I need to access a Windows 2008 Server with MS-SQL-Management-Studio and/or RDP via OpenVPN.

The connection to other servers (2003) in that particular network is no problem (rdp and sql), those also answer pings.

Not so 2008.

I did enable all File and Print - rule in the firewall - still no joy.

Any ideas what causes this?

Update:

```
IP of my 2008 Server: 10.0.0.238
and 2003: 10.0.0.235
Both subnets: 255.255.255.0

My VPN-IP: 10.0.8.6 
subnet: 255.255.255.252
```

I have no problems between the two Servers.
I even can ping/rdp/ms-sql-connect to the 2003 server over VPN

The File/Printershare (Echo ICPMv4 and v6) for in and outbound rules in Domain and Private/Public Profiles are all set to Scope: LocalIP,Remote IP "Beliebig" (meaning Any) -

I also tried to set the scopes of all in-out-v4-v6-Domain/Privat-Public rules to 
Remote-IP: 10.0.8.4/30

What puzzles me is that I can ping/connect via RDP and connect to SQL from a 2003-server on that subnet to the 2008-server

Comment: Is the default gateway of the 2008 server set correctly?

Comment: Being able to ping a host has absolutely no bearing on being able to connect to it via RDP or SSMS.

Comment: IP of my 2008 Server: 10.0.0.238
and 2003: 10.0.0.235
Both subnets: 255.255.255.0 My VPN-IP: 10.0.8.6 subnet: 255.255.255.252 I have no problems between the two Servers.
I even can ping/rdp/ms-sql-connect to the 2003 server over VPN The File/Printershare (Echo ICPMv4 and v6) for in and outbound rules in Domain and Private/Public Profiles are all set to Scope: LocalIP,Remote IP "Beliebig" (meaning Any) - I also tried to set the scopes of all in-out-v4-v6-Domain/Privat-Public rules to Remote-IP: 10.0.8.4/30 What puzzles me is that I can ping/connect via RDP and connect to SQL from a 2003-server

Answer (score 2):

You need make sure you have your firewall rule enabled to accept ICMP and RDP for different subnets. Look in the "scope" section of the ICMP rules. By default Windows Server 2008 will only return pings and allwo RDP from the same subnet as it is on. You are on a different subnet, because you are accessing the machine via VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open a remote session to the 2008 server from the 2003 you can reach trough the VPN.  That might help you understand why you can't reach the 2008 server through the VPN.

Comment: I can rdp from home -> 2003 -> 2008 - that does not help me any further as to why I cannot rpd from home -> 2008